# Record lesson as completed when user finishes watching vimeo video

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vimeo-api

I built a website in laravel 5 that have  training lessons with videos about various subjects. I use vimeo as my video library. Can anybody tell me how does laracasts or udemy mark the lesson as completed when the user finishes watching a video? I tried to google it with no luck.

Comment: `Laracast` use `custom video players` like [Video JS](http://www.videojs.com). If you use custom video player you can easily detect by using player's API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vimeo has an API that can fire a javascript event if the video ends, check [developer guide on vimeo](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api). In the `OnFinish` event you can do an ajax call that marks the video as watched. You can even use the `onPlayProgress` event and mark the video as watched when someone has watched a video for, let's say 90%, based on `getCurrentTime()` and `getDuration()`

Check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/bdougherty/pen/JgDfm) for a detailed example on the API usage.